# Alarm manager not working in android API 4.4

Tags: android, alarmmanager

I want to trigger alarm manger at 10 pm  in  everyday in android application. It is working in above Lolipop version but not working in KitKat version.

```
 public static void startAlarmManagerOutTime(Context context) {

    Calendar currentCal = Calendar.getInstance();

    Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
    calendar.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
    calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 22);
    calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE,00);

    long intendedTime = calendar.getTimeInMillis();
    long currentTime = currentCal.getTimeInMillis();



    alarmManager = (AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    Intent gpsTrackerIntent = new Intent(context1, AlarmReceiver.class);

    PendingIntent  pendingOutTimeIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 2, gpsTrackerIntent, 0);

    if(intendedTime >= currentTime){
        // you can add buffer time too here to ignore some small differences in milliseconds
        // set from today
        alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, intendedTime, AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, pendingOutTimeIntent);

    } else{
        // set from next day
        // you might consider using calendar.add() for adding one day to the current day
        calendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
        intendedTime = calendar.getTimeInMillis();

        alarmManager.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, intendedTime, AlarmManager.INTERVAL_DAY, pendingOutTimeIntent);
    }

}
```

This is broadcast receiver

```
 public class AlarmReceiver extends WakefulBroadcastReceiver {

 @Override
  public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

   Toast.makeText(context,"AlarmReceiver",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

  }
 }
```

I have put these values in my manifest:

```
 <receiver android:name=".com.test.Receiver.AlarmReceiver">
    </receiver>
```

Answer (score 0):

as far as I know since api lvl 19 repeating alarms are inexact. This mean if you set it for a certain hour it can trigger to another time near that date. This was added to save resources.
To check if an alarm is set, what I recommend is to use the adb command:

**adb shell dumpsys alarm**

If you are using linux or mac you could add a grep after that to search your app package name. The time there is displayed in millis, so you will have to convert that number to a date.

Something that I forgot, you are using a WakefulBroadcastReceiver but have you declared the permission **WAKE_LOCK** ?